# How can I underline an ListBoxItem in WPF?

Tags: wpf, formatting, listboxitem

How can I underline an ListBoxItem in WPF? I'm using the following but the underline does not appear.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="Phrase_List">
    <ListBoxItem IsSelected="{Binding IsDefault}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Phrase}" Tag="{Binding Path=ID}" TextDecorations="Underline"  />
    </ListBoxItem>
</DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what code you are trying to use. Please try to complete your question. I've used the following code to underline the 'World' item in my little ListBox.

```
    <ListBox>
        <ListBoxItem>Hello</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>
            <Underline>World</Underline>
        </ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a textblock, and set the textdecorations property to underline. Remember the contents of a ListBoxItem can be things other than text, hence why it's not a simple case of setting some property on the ListBoxItem.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create an item template that displays your text in a TextBlock control.  On the TextBlock, set the TextDecorations property (which is a collection) to contain 'Underline'.

Answer (score 0):

In XAML:

```
<ListBox Name="lst">
      <ListBoxItem Content="item1" />
      <ListBoxItem Content="item2" FontStyle="Italic" FontWeight="Normal" />
</ListBox>
```

In C#:

```
lst.Items.Clear();
lst.Items.Add(new ListBoxItem { Content = "item 1" });
lst.Items.Add(new ListBoxItem { Content = "item 2" });
lst.Items.Add(new ListBoxItem { Content = "item 3" });

ListBoxItem l = (ListBoxItem)lstItems.Items[2];
li.SetValue(TextElement.FontStyleProperty, FontStyles.Italic);
```